# ASP.NET crop image does not crop it

Tags: arrays, asp.net, vb.net, bitmap, crop

I want to resize an image to a max width and height and then crop it.
The resizing works. But the cropping [code I found here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-crop-image-and-save-the-cropped-image-using-asp-net-jquery) does not.

My own existing code uses a byte array, so I need to work with that.

So the code below does resize, does NOT crop, and does save the new image. What am I doing wrong with the cropping?

```
Dim imgNewWidth, imgNewHeight As Integer

Dim _originalThumbWidth As Integer = 900
Dim _originalThumbHeight As Integer = 900

Dim imageURL As String = "https://med.stanford.edu/news/all-news/2021/09/cat-fur-color-patterns/_jcr_content/main/image.img.780.high.jpg/cat_by-Kateryna-T-Unsplash.jpg"
Dim localImagePath As String = Server.MapPath("images\_tmp\") + "CROPPED.jpg"

ResizeAndSaveFast(_originalThumbWidth, _originalThumbHeight, imageURL, localImagePath, "", "", imgNewWidth, imgNewHeight)



  Private Function ResizeAndSaveFast(ByVal maxWidth As Integer, ByVal maxHeight As Integer, ByVal imageURL As String, ByVal saveToPath As String, ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String,
                                    ByRef imgNewWidth As Integer, ByRef imgNewHeight As Integer) As Boolean

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

        Dim imgRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(imageURL)
        Dim imgResponse As WebResponse
        Dim memStream As New MemoryStream

        Try
            imgResponse = imgRequest.GetResponse()
            Dim streamPhoto As Stream = imgResponse.GetResponseStream()
            streamPhoto.CopyTo(memStream)
            memStream.Position = 0
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try


        Dim bfPhoto As BitmapFrame = ReadBitmapFrame(memStream)
        Dim newWidth, newHeight As Integer
        Dim scaleFactor As Double

        newWidth = bfPhoto.PixelWidth
        newHeight = bfPhoto.PixelHeight

        imgNewWidth = newWidth
        imgNewHeight = newHeight

        If bfPhoto.PixelWidth > maxWidth Or bfPhoto.PixelHeight > maxHeight Then
            If bfPhoto.PixelWidth > maxWidth Then
                scaleFactor = maxWidth / bfPhoto.PixelWidth
                newWidth = CInt(Math.Round(bfPhoto.PixelWidth * scaleFactor, 0))
                newHeight = CInt(Math.Round(bfPhoto.PixelHeight * scaleFactor, 0))
            End If
            If newHeight > maxHeight Then
                scaleFactor = maxHeight / newHeight
                newWidth = CInt(Math.Round(newWidth * scaleFactor, 0))
                newHeight = CInt(Math.Round(newHeight * scaleFactor, 0))
            End If
        End If

        imgNewWidth = newWidth
        imgNewHeight = newHeight

        Dim bfResize As BitmapFrame = FastResize(bfPhoto, newWidth, newHeight)

        Dim baResize As Byte() = ToByteArray(bfResize)

        Dim bmp As System.Drawing.Bitmap = imageFunctions.ConvertByteArrayToBitmap(baResize)

        Dim CropArea As Rectangle = New Rectangle(100, 100, bmp.Width - 100, bmp.Height - 100)
        Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(CropArea.Width, CropArea.Height)


        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
            g.DrawImage(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height),
                             CropArea,
                             GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        End Using


        bm.Save(saveToPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        Return True


    End Function
```

Comment: From a quick look I think that you may change the "g.DrawImage(bm ...." to "g.DrawImage(bmp ...." (?) you aren't using the bmp variable anywhere which is the bitmap that you want to crop (I assume). I think that the posted answer is correct however incomplete.

Comment: Thanks. When I change my code to `Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` the result is just a completely black image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo caused by using variable names that are too similar.  As written, you have this block of code:

```
Dim bmp As System.Drawing.Bitmap = imageFunctions.ConvertByteArrayToBitmap(baResize)

Dim CropArea As Rectangle = New Rectangle(100, 100, bmp.Width - 100, bmp.Height - 100)
Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(CropArea.Width, CropArea.Height)


Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
            g.DrawImage(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height),
                             CropArea,
                             GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
End Using
```

This line:

```
g.DrawImage(bm, 
            New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height),
            CropArea,
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

Should be:

```
g.DrawImage(bmp, 
            New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height),
            CropArea,
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```

In your code, you created the variable `bmp` to store the non-cropped bitmap.  In other words, your source data.

You then declare `bm` to store the cropped bitmap, your destination. The Graphics object `g` is created using the destination.

in your call to `g.DrawImage`, the first argument should be the source data, `bmp`.  Instead you have the destination, `bm` there.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more question then, how would I center the area to be cropped in the center of the original image?

Comment: You have to calculate an offset for x and y in your `CropArea`.  For a given dimension, find the difference between original dimension and cropped dimension.  The offset is 1/2 that difference, and is what you use in the `Rectangle()` constructor when creating `CropArea`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but I think you should be using a different variable in this line of code.

```
g.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height),
                         CropArea,
                         GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
```